# php-jquery-pdf load a pdf on a div

Tags: php, jquery, pdf

I'm trying to display by jquery load() a dynamically generated PDF created by PHP with FPDFlib on a div but what I get is a jam of chars. Is there a way to resolve it?

thanks in advance

I've tried to correct my code in this way but continue to display jam

```
    $.post("./php/stampa_login.php",
    {piatta:'<? echo $_POST["piatta"] ?>'}, 
    function(data){
        $("#stampa_content").load("./temp/login.pdf")
});
```

ciao

h.

Comment: can we see your code please, seems like an output issue.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be correct. jQuery's load() fetches an URL through AJAX; if that URL is PDF, it appears as "jam of chars" to the browser, as PDF and HTML aren't compatible *at all*, the formats are completely different.

What you probably want is to open the PDF as an `<object>`, but then you're hoping that the user has some PDF plugin installed in their browser. Let's take a step back: what are you trying to achieve here, by displaying a PDF?

Comment: I load by JQuery php page that generate PDF; I suppose that this is the problem, may be I can resolve amkeing a post request to php page that generate PDF, save it in local and after load for display...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a blank `embed` tag and give `src` attribute as link. in your call back function. This will load the pdf file perfectly.

```
 $("#embed_tag_id").attr("src", "./temp/login.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using $("#whatever").load();

You'll want something like this:

```
$("#stampa_content").html ($("<object>", {
  data : "./temp/login.pdf",
  type : "application/pdf",
  width : 800,
  height : 600
}));
```

What that will do is instead of trying to load the contents of the PDF into a DIV, it will create an `<object>` block that will start up your PDF reader (such as Adobe Reader) which will then load the PDF itself and display it.

Answer (score 0):

ya, seems to be an output issue.  Have you tried header function to output it correctly ?  try for proper output or instead of opening the pdf in div, just update the pdf's link there

Comment: I use these headers: header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
   header("Content-type: application/pdf");

Comment: I don't think that this will work.  You will have to update the div with the link for the newly generated pdf.